# How to split an Odd array

Tags: arrays, swift

If I have an array `[-23,0,43,7,5,2,4]`, how to do I split the array [odd][even]. 
I want 4 elements in the first array and 3 elements in the second array.

I tried to do something like this:

```
let leftArray = Array(mainArray[0..<mainArray.count/2])
let rightArray = Array(mainArray[mainArray.count/2..<mainArray.count])
```

I keep on getting `[-23,0,43]` and `[7,5,2,4]`.

Comment: add a `+1` after `...count/2`

Comment: Change it to 0...mainArray.count/2 and (mainArray.count/2 + 1)..<mainArray.count

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The question is very clear. He is getting [-23,0,43] [7,5,2,4]. but he expects [-23,0,43,7][5,2,4].

Comment: @LeoDabus Is it really since several of the answers is going for a completely different solution dividing the array in odd and even numbers?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Read it again. Look at OP attempt and you will see why those answers are downvoted. Btw not my downvote but they did deserve it.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'e seen plenty of attempts that won't do the expected result and total misunderstanding of what is happening. `I split the array [odd][even]` is misleading here. Giving the expected result would clarify for everyone.

Comment: Look at the names OP chose to the result `left` and `right`. **"I want 4 elements in the first array and 3 elements in the second array."**  then **"I keep on getting [-23,0,43] [7,5,2,4]"** Lets see what OP says.

Comment: @Larme if op wanted to just separate odd from even numbers he wouldn't care about how many elements would be on each resulting array

Comment: Varun, I updated my answer. Your original question was unclear.

Comment: I  asked my first question about the expected result since I thought the question needed clarification because it was very obvious it could and was being interpreted in different ways. I don't care which is right since I have no intention to post an answer but the clarification is, in my opinion, clearly needed.  The main source of confusion is this "...split the array [odd][even]" as I see it. I have voted to close this as needing clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to split your array in the middle, and for odd counts, have the first part be the larger one. Use a function like this (intentionally spelled our very explicitly):

```
func splitArray(_ arr: [Int]) -> ([Int], [Int]) {
    let count = arr.count
    let half = count.isMultiple(of: 2) ? count / 2 : count / 2 + 1
    let left = arr[0..<half]
    let right = arr[half..<count]
    return (Array(left), Array(right))
}

splitArray([-23,0,43,7,5,2,4])   // ([-23, 0, 43, 7], [5, 2, 4])
splitArray([-23,0,43,7,5,2,4,1]) // ([-23, 0, 43, 7], [5, 2, 4, 1])
```

This can be simplified and be made generic (i.e., work on all kinds of Collections) like so:

```
extension Collection {
    func splitHalf() -> (SubSequence, SubSequence) {
        let count = self.count
        let left = self.prefix(count / 2 + count % 2)
        let right = self.suffix(count / 2)
        return (left, right)
    }
}

[-23,0,43,7,5,2,4].splitHalf()   // ([-23, 0, 43, 7], [5, 2, 4])
[-23,0,43,7,5,2,4,1].splitHalf() // ([-23, 0, 43, 7], [5, 2, 4, 1])
"12345".splitHalf() // (.0 "123", .1 "45")
"123456".splitHalf() // (.0 "123", .1 "456")
```

Comment: Much simpler `let index = count/2 + count % 2` and you can use half open operators  `let first = arr[..<index]` and `let last = arr[index...]` Btw better to return two array slices instead of duplicating its elements initializing two new arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an extension implementing properties that yield the left and right halves of the array. In this implementation `left` includes the larger half of the array if the array has an odd number of elements.

```
extension Array {
    var left: ArraySlice<Element> {
        prefix(count / 2 + count % 2)
    }
    var right: ArraySlice<Element> {
        suffix(count / 2)
    }
}
```

And its usage would be:

```
let main = [-23, 0, 43, 7, 5, 2, 4]
let left = main.left
let right = main.right
```

The result of the above is an `ArraySlice` for efficiency, but if you want an `Array` you can just use `map`.

```
let main = [-23, 0, 43, 7, 5, 2, 4]
let left = main.left.map { $0 }
let right = main.right.map { $0 }
```

Comment: Better to extend Collection and return a SubSequence. This would allow you to use those methods on Strings as well. Btw you are accessing the array count twice. `extension Collection {
    var left: SubSequence {
        let count = self.count
        return prefix(count / 2 + count % 2)
    }
    var right: SubSequence {
        suffix(count/2)
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

Function for split the array

```
func getSplitArr(arr:[Int])->Void{

    let count = arr.count
    let secArrCount = abs(count/2)

    var firstArray = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<secArrCount{
        let value = arr[i]
        firstArray.append(value)
    }

    var secondArray = [Int]()
    for i in secArrCount..<count{
        let value = arr[i]
        secondArray.append(value)
    }

    print("\(firstArray)")
    print("\(secondArray)")

}
```

Use of Functions

```
self.getSplitArr(arr: [-23,0,43,7,5,2,4])
```

Comment: Not related to the intent of the question but `abs(count/2)` is pointless. the result of this operation `count/2` will always be positive

Answer (score -1):

Your first question wasn't clear. This should return two arrays one where the first array is even and the second is odd every time.

```
var array = [-23,0,43,7,5,2,4]

func splitArray(in array : [Int]) -> (firstArray :[Int], secondArray: [Int]) {

    let firstArray = array.dropLast(array.count / 2).compactMap { item -> Int in
        item
    }

    let secondArray = array.dropFirst((array.count / 2) + 1).compactMap { item -> Int in
        item
    }

    return (firstArray,secondArray)
}

var newArray = splitArray(in: array)

print(newArray)
```

Comment: Varun Poondi your question wasn't clear. I have revised my answer accordingly.